# How to limit the number of lines for string data in React?

Tags: reactjs

In my React app, I have some data column named description. It has a too long paragraph inside, so I want to limit the number of lines by truncating it to 1 or 2 lines.

I looked up some useful plugin and I found [react-lines-ellipsis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lines-ellipsis?activeTab=readme) and it successfully worked except for untrucating it back.

The plugin truncates the paragraph to 1 or 2 lines, and the truncated part is shows as `...`. I wanna untruncate it back when I click the `...`. Is there a way for me to able to do that? or is there any other plugin to support that?

import HTMLEllipsis from "react-lines-ellipsis/lib/html";
import responsiveHOC from "react-lines-ellipsis/lib/responsiveHOC";

```
const Slider = props => {

  const handleReflow = rleState => {
    const { clamped, text, unsafeHTML } = rleState;
    console.log(unsafeHTML);     <---- prints undefined
  };

  return (
    ...
    <ResponsiveEllipsis
      unsafeHTML = {store.description}
      onReflow = {handleReflow}
      maxLine = {1}
      ellipsis = "..."
    />
    ...
  )
}
```

Comment: Well that plugin you linked to supports expanding it, you can see it in the example the Github page links to: https://xiaody.github.io/react-lines-ellipsis/  that being said, this is quite a simple functionality, you'd probably just be better of making it yourself rather than bringing in plugins and modules. By the time you look for them, and read through the docs, and figure out workarounds for what the plugin doesn't allow, then you could've just made it yourself, and you'll know all the code and can customise it much easier

Comment: Dependencies are usually for things that are very large in scope, or that you simply can't figure out yourself. Not for every little functionality.

Comment: @Jayce444 Didn't mean to look like I'm not putting any efforts for that, but I'm really confused about using the plugin. After checking your comments, I tried above codes in my origin post, but couldn't have figure out how to access the unsafeHTML to update it in the callback function.

Comment: It says you could use `html` instead of `text` if you prefer `unsafeHTML` (Please see the section `Experimental html truncation`).
I have had a similar use case in my code and at least I managed to `console.log` the output html, clamped or not.


`handleReflow = (rleState) => { const { clamped, html } = rleState...  console.log(html);}`